# My code won't understand blank space (' ') and will finish the code

Tags: c

I am writing a code that translates words and sentences into morse code. It works with words but when I want to form a sentence, it will close itself after the first word.

I tried to use different delay functions, changing ' ' into '0\' but they didn't work

```
int main() {
    char Morse[999];

    printf("Enter anything you want to be translated to morse\n");
    scanf("%s", Morse);


for (int i = 0, length = strlen(Morse); i < length; i++)
    switch (Morse[i]) {
        case ' ':
            Sleep(600);
            break;
        case 'a':
            Beep(440, 150);
            Beep(440, 300);
            break;
```

I want it to have a delay of 600 millisecond when it sees a space

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to read a line of text. Note: You have to remove or skip the trailing `'\n'` in your input buffer. BTW: Instead of using `Beep(440, 150)` or `Beep(440, 300)` in several places I suggest to define functions `dit()` and `dah()` and use these.

Comment: For reference, the scanf conversion specifiers are [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You can just look them up and see, for example, that `%s` _matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters_.

Comment: I don't know how to use fgets as I never used it. Also, if %s won't scan a space, what should I use?

Comment: fgets solved my problem, thanks everyone!

Comment: OT: but the code in the `switch (Morse[i]` block looks very, very poor to me. This is the wrong approach.

Comment: and don't call `strlen` in a loop. Save the result to a variable, or `strlen` will be called again and again unnecessarily

Comment: The `Sleep()` function is not portable.  Suggest calling `nanosleep() with an appropriate parameter.

Comment: The posted code, when expanded to handle all the different morse characters will be massive (and error prone)  Suggest implementing a table, where each entry in the table is a string of '.' and '-' to represent the associated morse character.  Then implement a simple subroutine that string from the table and output it

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", Morse);`  This will stop scanning when it sees any 'white space'  Suggest: using `fgets( Morse, sizeof(Morse), stdin );`  or `scanf( "%998[^\n]",  Morse );`

Answer (score 1):

You should use fgets instead of scanf to get a sentence (string with spaces)

```
int main() {
    char Morse[999];

    printf("Enter anything you want to be translated to morse\n");
    fgets(Morse, sizeof(Morse), stdin);


    for (int i = 0, length = strlen(Morse); i < length; i++)
        switch (Morse[i]) {
        case ' ':
            Sleep(600);
            break;
        case 'a':
            Beep(440, 150);
            Beep(440, 300);
            break;
```

Hope it works for you.